# Pyqt5. How to clear QVBoxLayout by a Signal?

Tags: pyqt5

I try to clear QVBoxLayout with `self.vbox.takeAt(0)`, but previous vboxes clog up the QWidget and would not go away. New appear on top of the old ones.

Whole code https://pastebin.com/n43BH1R0

```
class Worker(QObject):
    CLEAR_VBOX = pyqtSignal()
    intReady = pyqtSignal(int)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def procCounter(self):
        for i in range(1, 100):
            self.CLEAR_VBOX.emit()
            self.intReady.emit(i)
            time.sleep(1)

class Form(QWidget):
    ..
    ..
    def initUI(self):
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)

        self.setGeometry(333, 333, 222, 222)
        self.show()

    def clearvbox(self):
        while self.vbox.count():
            # ~ # break
            self.vbox.takeAt(0)

    def onIntReady(self, i):
        hbox = QHBoxLayout()

        for ii in range(i):
            ll = QLabel(str(random.randint(1,9)))       
            hbox.addWidget(ll)

        self.vbox.addLayout(hbox)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def clearvbox(self, L = False):
    if not L:
        L = self.vbox
    if L is not None:
        while L.count():
            item = L.takeAt(0)

            widget = item.widget()

            if widget is not None:
                widget.deleteLater()
            else:
                self.clearvbox(item.layout())
```